# A loop never starts

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

I'm writing a simple function that is supposed to read an input from a user as a string. Check if the strings solely consist of digits then converts it to and int and returns it. The problem is the loop never used regardless of the input. I'm struggling to find the root of the problem.

```
int correctInt()
{
    string temp;
    int input;
    bool m;
    do
    {
        m = false;
        getline(cin, temp);
        int length=temp.length();

        for (int a = 0; a < length; a++)
        {
            if (temp[a] < '0' && temp[a]>'9')
            {
                cout << "ID should consist of numbers. Try again: ";
                m = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!m)
        {
            return input = atoi(temp.c_str());
        }
    } while (1);
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can `temp[a]` be both less than `'0'` and greater than `'9'` at the same time?

Comment: the loop is executed but you need to review the `if` inside that loop. What character is `< '0'` and `> ' 9'` at the same time? Voting to close as typo

Comment: I suggest you learn about [the standard character classification functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte#Character_classification), more specifically [`std::isdigit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit). Also some [standard algorithm function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) could be good to know, like [`std::all_of`, `std::any_of`, and `std::none_of`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of).

Comment: Or just use [`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) which have validation built-in.

Comment: If you print something in all cases, you will see that the loop *is* entered. Misdiagnosing the problem often makes you look in the wrong place for the bug.

Answer (score 2):

You should use OR instead of AND:

```
temp[a] < '0' || temp[a]>'9'
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes more sense. Now that I think about it

Answer (score 0):

Try to change && (and) condition to || (or) condition

```
if (temp[a] < '0' || temp[a]>'9')
```